# Taming meta implication in Isar proofs

Tags: isabelle, isar

Proving a simple theorem I came across meta-level implications in the proof. Is it OK to have them or could they be avoided? If I should handle them, is this the right way to do so?

```
theory Sandbox
imports Main
begin

lemma "(x::nat) > 0 ∨ x = 0"
proof (cases x)
  assume "x = 0"
  show "0 < x ∨ x = 0" by (auto)
next
  have "x = Suc n ⟹ 0 < x" by (simp only: Nat.zero_less_Suc)
  then have "x = Suc n ⟹ 0 < x ∨ x = 0" by (auto)
  then show "⋀nat. x = Suc nat ⟹ 0 < x ∨ x = 0" by (auto)
qed

end
```

I guess this could be proved more easily but I wanted to have a structured proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle meta-implication `==>` is nothing to be avoided (in fact its the "native" way to express inference rules in Isabelle). There is a canonical way that often allows us to avoid meta-implication when writing Isar proofs. E.g., for a general goal

```
"!!x. A ==> B"
```

we can write in Isar

```
fix x
assume "A"
...
show "B"
```

For your specific example, when looking at it in Isabelle/jEdit you might notice that
the `n` of the second case is highlighted. The reason is that it is a free variable. While this is not a problem per se, it is more canonical to fix such variables locally (like the typical statement "for an arbitrary but fixed ..." in textbooks). E.g.,

```
next
  fix n
  assume "x = Suc n"
  then have "0 < x" by (simp only: Nat.zero_less_Suc)
  then show "0 < x ∨ x = 0" ..
qed
```

Here it can again be seen how `fix`/`assume`/`show` in Isar corresponds to the actual goal, i.e.,

```
1. ⋀nat. x = Suc nat ⟹ 0 < x ∨ x = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

When writing structured proofs, it is best to avoid meta-implication (and quantification) for the outermost structure of the subgoal. I.e. instead of talking about

```
⋀x. P x ⟹ Q x ⟹ R x
```

you should use

```
fix x
assume "P x" "Q x"
...
show "R x"
```

If `P x` and `Q x` have some structure, it is fine to use meta-implication and -quantification for these.

There is a number of reasons to prefer `fix`/`assumes` over the meta-operators in structured proofs.

- Somewhat trivially, you do not have to state them again in every have and show statement.
- More important, when you use `fix` to quantify a variable, it stays the same in the whole proof. If you use `⋀`, it is freshly quantified in each `have` statement (and doesn't exist outside). This makes it impossible to refer to this variable directly and often complicates the search space for automated tools. Similar things hold for `assume` vs `⟹`.
- A more intricate point is the behaviour of `show` in the presence of meta-implications. Consider the following proof attempt:

  ```
  lemma "P ⟷ Q"
  proof
    show "P ⟹ Q" sorry
  next
    show "Q ⟹ P" sorry
  qed
  ```

  After the `proof` command, there are two subgoals: `P ⟹ Q` and `Q ⟹ P`. Nevertheless, the final `qed` fails. How did this happen?

  The first `show` applies the rule `P ⟹ Q` to the first applicable subgoal, namely `P ⟹ Q`. Using the usual rule resolution mechanism of Isabelle, this yields `P ⟹ P` (`assume P`show Q` would have removed the subgoal).

  The second `show` applies the rule `Q ⟹ P` to the first applicable subgoal: This is now `P ⟹ P` (as `Q ⟹ P` is the second subgoal), yielding `P ⟹ Q` again.

  As a result, we are still have the two subgoals `P ⟹ Q` and `Q ⟹ P` and `qed` cannot close the goal.

  In many cases, we don't notice this behaviour of `show`, as trivial subgoals like `P ⟹ P` can be solved by `qed`.

A few words on the behavior of `show`: As we have seen above, meta-implication in `show` does not correspond to `assume`. Instead, it corresponds to `assume`s lesser known brother, `presume`. `presume` allows you to introduce new assumptions, but requires you to discharge them afterwards. As an example, compare

```
lemma "P 2 ⟹ P 0"
proof -
  presume "P 1" then show "P 0" sorry
next
  assume "P 2" then show "P 1" sorry
qed
```

and

```
lemma "P 2 ⟹ P 0"
proof -
  show "P 1 ⟹ P 0" sorry
next
  assume "P 2" then show "P 1" sorry
qed
```